# Interactive dashboard for time series data

Tags: time-series, visualization

I'm searching for some tools that allow me to build a dashboard in order to visualize information about time series. This dashboard needs to be interactive and allows to be integrated into a web site (like a web application).

I made some projects with D3.js, but for this one I would prefer something faster in term of implementation (python+matplotlib like).

What kind of options do I have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

D3 (data Driven Documents) is a great and powerful tool, but does require a certain afinity for JavaScript. There are a few tools that piggy-back off it though and are more friendly to the aspiring data scientist and plotly is behind a few others. All are easier to use compared to D3 in my opinion.

Check out a few of the following:

- [Bokeh](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/) (python)
- [Dash](https://plot.ly/products/dash/) (python - based on plotly, looks very promising!)
- [Plotly](https://plot.ly/) (many languages)
- [Shiny](https://rstudio.github.io/shinydashboard/) (R)

Here is [a comparison of Bokeh and Dash](https://blog.sicara.com/bokeh-dash-best-dashboard-framework-python-shiny-alternative-c5b576375f7f).

Here is [a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12977517/python-equivalent-of-d3-js) on StackOverflow.